# Ajax POST request not hitting Elixir router path

Tags: react-native, ecto, elixir, elixir-poison

I have this redux-observable epic which does a POST ajax request using [RxJS.ajax.post](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS-DOM/blob/master/doc/operators/post.md) and I don't think it is hitting my Elixir router properly as nothing is happening on my elixir backend. I am doing get requests to get categories correctly and in the same manner so I am hitting other paths in my Elixir router correctly. I am expecting the issue to be with my backend Elixir code not my frontend. I might need to change my path in `router.ex`.

When I press a button on the frontend, this object is what gets sent to the elixir backend (it dispatches this action with a product as the payload and hits the redux-observable epic below):

```
onPress = {() => {
  props.uploadProduct({
    name: props.name,
    brand: props.brand,
    description: props.description,
    image: props.image
  })
```

The epic:

```
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/observable/dom/ajax'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'

export const uploadProductEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(UPLOAD_PRODUCT)
    .mergeMap(action => {
      ajax.post('http://localhost:4000/products/', action.payload)
    })
    .map(response => uploadProductFulfilled(response))
    .catch(error => Observable.of(
      uploadProductRejected(error))
    )
```

the elixir router:

```
defmodule Api.Router do
  use Plug.Router

  if Mix.env == :dev do
    use Plug.Debugger
  end
  plug :match
  plug :dispatch

  get "/categories/" do
    Api.Repo.getCategories(conn)
  end

  post "/products/:product" do
    IO.puts inspect conn
    Api.Repo.insertProduct(conn, product)
  end
end
```

`IO.puts inspect conn` doesn't log anything. So My Elixir router path `post "/products/:product" do` is not being hit by my POST request. What am I doing wrong?

This is the elixir function in `repo.ex` that I HOPE will insert the product into my database:

```
  def insertProduct(conn, product) do
    product = %Api.Product{name: product.name, brand: product.brand, description: product.description, image: product.image, rating: 0, numberOfVotes: 0}
    changeset = Api.Product.changeset(product)
    errors = changeset.errors
    valid = changeset.valid?
    case insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, product} ->
        conn
          |> put_resp_content_type("application/json")
          |> send_resp(200, Poison.encode!(%{
              successs: "success"
          }))
      {:error, changeset} ->
        conn
          |> put_resp_content_type("application/json")
          |> send_resp(500, Poison.encode!(%{
              failure: "Errors"
          }))
    end
  end
```

I am a frontend developer just trying to get into Elixir so any guidance and patience is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your JS code is POSTing to `/products`, not `/products/:product`.

Comment: Thanks. So If I remove the `:product`, from the `router.ex` file, Do I have a way to get the product object on the backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is sent in the body of the request, not in the URL, so the route should be:

```
post "/products"
```

You'll also need to plug in a JSON parser after `plug :match` and before `plug :dispatch`, as described in the Parameter Parsing section in the documentation of `Plug.Router`:

```
plug :match
plug Plug.Parsers, parsers: [:json],
                   pass:  ["application/json"],
                   json_decoder: Poison
plug :dispatch
```

The JSON data will now be present in `conn.body_params`, which you can send to your function:

```
post "/products" do
  Api.Repo.insertProduct(conn, conn.body_params)
end
```

And finally, the keys in the JSON would be strings, so you need to use the bracket syntax to access them instead of dots:

```
product = %Api.Product{name: product["name"], brand: product["brand"], description: product["description"], image: product["image"], rating: 0, numberOfVotes: 0}
```

---

I'm not sure how you've defined `Api.Product.changeset`, but the default Phoenix convention defines a 2 arity function which calls `cast` and extracts the data from a map itself. If you're doing the same, you can do this instead:

```
changeset = Api.Product.changeset(%Api.Product{}, product)
```

Comment: Thanks!! It still doesn't appear to hit my router. I tried to add an IO.puts in the router and I get nothing logging. eg:  

  `post "/products" do
    IO.puts inspect conn
    Api.Repo.insertProduct(conn, conn.body_params)
  end`

Comment: Can you see in the JS console if your code `ajax.post('http://localhost:4000/products/'` is even being executed or not? You can see the requests being made in the Network tab in Chrome's DevTools.

Comment: But i know it was running the line of code that makes the ajax POST because it this line of code dispatches an action which did get dispatched `.catch(error => Observable.of(
      uploadProductRejected(error))
    )`

Comment: I deleted a message above my last one because it became irrelevant. I am unable to see network requests in the chrome dev console due to using react native which doesn't allow that without some hacks which I haven't got working. Can confirm the ajax request gets sent as it dispatches `uploadProductRejected`. No error details though. Admittedly I haven't used [RxJS.ajax.post](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS-DOM/blob/master/doc/operators/post.md) before now so I'd love to know if the ajax request gets sent properly. I'm working on that right now.

Comment: I have just confirmed it isn't sending the network request to `/products`. Will get that working hopefully soon then can test this solution. Thanks!